# Unable to migrate the filters.php file from laravel 4 to laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5

I just inherited a laravel application and need to migrate it from 4 to 5. Everything is good after following the guide except the filters.php file.

The guide says to move them to the boot method of `RouteServiceProvider`  and replace before filter with `middleware` but it just won't work. I am new to laravel and not sure how everything works.

This is one of the filters i am trying to migrate:

```
Route::filter('campaign.edit', function($route)
{
$campaign_id = $route->getParameter('id');
if (is_null(Namespace\Campaign::find($campaign_id))) {
    if (Input::get('campaign_id')) {
        $campaign_id = Input::get('campaign_id');
    } else if (Input::get('track_id')) {
        $track_id = Input::get('track_id');
        $track = Namespace\Track::find($track_id);
        $campaign_id = $track->campaign_id;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
if (false === Auth::user()->canEditCampaign($campaign_id)) {
    return App::abort(403);
}
});
```

How can I go about migrating this piece?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by taking that function and making a middleware out of it, such as the one below.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use NameSpace;
use Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CampaignEdit
{
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  $campaign_id = $request->route('id');
  if (is_null(NameSpace\Campaign::find($campaign_id))) {
    if (Input::get('campaign_id')) {
      $campaign_id = Input::get('campaign_id');
    } else if (Input::get('track_id')) {
      $track_id = Input::get('track_id');
      $track = NameSpace\Track::find($track_id);
      $campaign_id = $track->campaign_id;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
  if (false === Auth::user()->canEditCampaign($campaign_id)) {
    return App::abort(403);
  }


  return $next($request);
  }

}
```